# better way of selecting 1 to many?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have an express.js based rest application. Please have a look on following code and suggest me what would be better way.

I want to select user and its associated images (1 user has many images).

```
function getUser (connection, req, res) {
   var userId = req.params.id;
   connection.query('SELECT * FROM user p'
                    + ' WHERE p.id = ' + connection.escape(userId), function handleSql(err, rows) {
    if (err){ logAndRespond(err,res); return; }
    if (rows.length === 0){ res.send(204); return; }

    var adId = rows[0].adId;
    // load images
    connection.query('SELECT id, url FROM image WHERE ad_id = ' + connection.escape(adId), function (err, imgRows) {
        if (err){ logAndRespond(err,res); return; }
        if (rows.length != 0){ 
            rows[0].images = imgRows;
        }

        res.json({'user': rows});
        connection.release();
    });

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You don't have to escape parameters by yourself
- You don't release the connection if an error occurred

The problem now is I don't know what you want to do with selected rows. You are also checking the `rows.length` twice but if there weren't any records in the first query then the second one will not be executed.

```
    function getUser(conn, req, res) {
        conn.query("SELECT * FROM user p WHERE p.id = ?;", [req.params.id], function(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                return logAndRespond(err, res);
            }

            if (!rows.length) {
                return res.send(204);
            }

            conn.query("SELECT id, url FROM image WHERE ad_id = ?;", [rows[0].adId], function(err, imgRows) {
                if (err) {
                    return logAndRespond(err, res);
               }

               if (rows.length) {  // ???
                   rows[0].images = imgRows;
               }

               res.json({"user": rows});
               conn.release();
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: I select a user record and multiple images of that users. I want to sent this information (user and its images) in same json. This code does serve the puporse but I am wondering if there is any better way of achieving this.

Comment: Another, possibly better solution is to send just one query to the database. This query will select all data that you need.

Comment: one query will create repetition for user data for each of the image row